# How to know the varchar length from read nos schema in tera data?

Tags: teradata

I have a sql command  below, it can get  NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA
and return data column type.
BUT  I don't know varchar length, this makes a little trouble in crate a foreign Table.
How to know the **varchar length**???????

```
SELECT ParquetColumnName,TDColumnType
FROM READ_NOS_FM (
USING
STOREDAS('PARQUET')
FULLSCAN('TRUE')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA')
LOCATION('/s3/bXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/PARQUETDATA/)
) AS D;
```

result:

```
ParquetColumnName    TDColumnType
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GageHeight2                    FLOAT
Flow                           FLOAT
site_no                        BIGINT
datetime                       VARCHAR
Precipitation                  FLOAT
GageHeight                     FLOAT
```

Comment: With FULLSCAN('TRUE') the ParquetColumnMaxLength should have the maximum length found in the data for variable-length columns.

Comment: Copy your answer to the  answer field below ,  I'll chose your answer as the correct answer.  Tanks a lot  for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FULLSCAN('TRUE') the ParquetColumnMaxLength should have the maximum length found in the data for variable-length columns